# Absoluteness of $\mathbb{P}$-names

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In Kunen's book he says that $\mathbb{P}$-names are absolute for a transitive models of ZFC using a theorem to the effect that functions defined by recursion are absolute, i.e;

Let $R$,$A$,$G$ be defined (using formulas) and let $R$ be set like on $A$ and suppose that $R$ is a well ordering of $A$ and $G$ is a 2-ary function, then $F(a)=G(a,F(\downarrow(a)))$ for any $a\in{A}$ and $\emptyset$ otherwise is absolute for a transitive model $M$ of ZFC as long as $R, A, G$ are absolute for $M$ and $(R \text{ is set like on }A)^{M}$ and $a\downarrow\subseteq{M}$.

He then uses this on the definition for $\mathbb{P}$-names where $\tau$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name iff $\tau$ is a relation and $\forall\langle{\sigma,p}\rangle\in{\tau}$, $\sigma$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name and $p\in{\mathbb{P}}$ with $xRy$ iff $a\in\text{trcl}(y)$, $A$=V and $F(\tau)=1$ if $\forall\langle{\sigma,p}\rangle\in{\tau}$, $F(\sigma)=1$ and $p\in{\mathbb{P}}$ and $0$ otherwise. He does not define what $G$ is.

I can see that $R$, $A$ satisfies the requirements for the theorem. But what is $G$? I tried to the intuitive thing and define $G:V\times{V}\rightarrow{\{0,1\}}$ as $G(\tau,\mathbb{P})=1$ iff $\tau$ is a relation and $\forall\langle{\sigma,p}\rangle\in{\tau}$, $\sigma$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name and $G(\sigma,\mathbb{P})=1$ and $p\in{\mathbb{P}}$. But I can't figure out how $R$ helps with the recursion. I'm also not sure if $G$ is represented properly by a formula (since $G(\sigma,\mathbb{P})=1$ seems as if the formula referneces itself inside the formula which shouldn't happen).

Can someone please clarify the two points above? Thank you.

Comment: That can't be right. Add a Cohen real to $L$ and consider names of Cohen forcing in $L[r]$, there is a canonical name for $r$ which is not a canonical name of anything in $L$. So it's not in $L$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. But I think we also assume that $\mathbb{P}\in{M}$ which I think takes care of what you said. Please feel free to fix any errors that are there and in the question itself.

Comment: The Cohen forcing does not change between any two models of set theory with the same $\omega$. So it's not the case, and my comment still stands.

Comment: But that is all right isn't it? $L$ doesn't need to have all $\mathbb{P}$ names in it. This is just saying that as long as $\tau\in{M}$ and $\tau$ is $\mathbb{P}$-name, then $M$ also thinks that $\tau$ is $\mathbb{P}$-name.

Comment: When you just write "absolute" it is usually understood as up and down. It's true that it is upwards absolute, but my comment points how it is not downwards absolute.

Comment: Again, "absolute" means both upwards and downwards absoluteness. If you only mean "upwards absolute" then you should write that. My point is that **names are *not* downwards absolute**.

Comment: But absoluteness only makes sense if the thing you are talking about is in the base model, correct? That is how I have always thought of it. Allowing for that, do you have any idea as for how $G$ should be defined?

Comment: @Asaf: Kunen (at least new Kunen) only mentions downwards absoluteness (which he calls "absoluteness").

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thank you. That is the book I'm using. I wasn't aware there were two different notions. I guess in the sense that Asaf uses it, you have $\tau\in{M}$ by virtue of it being a $\mathbb{P}$-name?

Comment: Anyhow, I checked Kunen's older text as well, on pg 188 he says the same thing. I don't know if that is an error.

Comment: @AsafKaragila et all: I think this confusion is not from different definitions of absoluteness, but from which property we mean by “names are/are not absolute”. Absoluteness for the property “being a $\mathbb{P}$-name” says that for any $x \in M \subseteq N$, $M$ believes “$x$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name” if and only if $N$ believes “$x$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name”. (Here the *if* is the downwards direction, *only if* is upwards).  The property you suggest, that every $\mathbb{P}$-name in $N$ lies in $M$, would follow from absoluteness of the property “being the set of all $\mathbb{P}$-names”.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I agree that the *formula* $x$ is a $\mathbb P$-name is absolute between $M$ and $N$. But the general statement "Names are absolute" can be (and that is how I have) interpreted as "The class of $\Bbb P$-names in $N$ is the class of $\Bbb P$-names in $M$" (in a similar way of how $L$ is absolute).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The book sort of builds up what Peter said implicitly. I guess it got lost when I just posted the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in Theorem II.4.15 (p.123-124), the function $G$ must be defined on pairs $\langle x , f \rangle$ where $x$ is an element of the class $A$ under consideration, and $f$ is a function with domain $a{\downarrow}$.  Since our goal is to have $$F(a) = G ( a , F \restriction ( a{\downarrow} ) ),$$ we basically re-state the definition of the desired $F$ in terms of $G ( x , f )$ where $x$ and $f$ have the desired properties:

> $G(x,f) = 1$ iff $x$ is a relation and $f$ is a function such that $\mathrm{trcl}(x) \subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f)$ and for all $\langle y , z \rangle \in x$, $f(y) = 1$ and $z \in \mathbb{P}$; otherwise, $G(x,f) = 0$.

The relation $x \mathrel{R} y \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathrm{trcl}(y)$ is just meant to ensure that if $\langle \sigma , p \rangle \in \tau$, then $F(\sigma)$ is "already" defined, *i.e.*, it has "already" been checked whether $\sigma$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name. It could be replaced by a long-winded relation to the effect of $x \mathrel{R} y$ iff $x$ is the first coordinate of an element of $y$ or is the first coordinate of an element of the first coordinate of an element of $y$ or *&c*.

Comment: @DanulG: No problem!

Comment: Just one quick question though, I think that Kunen has both upwards and downwards absoluteness in his book. Did you mean for it to be interpreted in the sense that Asaf did here? (As pointed out by Peter in the above comments?)

Comment: @DanulG: You're right. I can't read too good right now.  Yes, it's pretty much exactly what Peter says in his comment above.  I've deleted my comment which was largely incorrect.

Comment: OK. Thanks again!

Comment: Just one quick question; shouldn't it be $\langle{y,z}\rangle\in{\text{trcl}(x)}$ as opposed to $\langle{y,z}\rangle\in{x}$?

Comment: @DanulG: Actually, no.  What if the conditions of your partial order are themselves pairs?  Then if $p = \langle s, F \rangle\in \mathbb{P}$ and $\langle \sigma , p \rangle \in \tau$ we have $\langle s , F \rangle \in \mathrm{trcl}(\tau)$, but $s$ will in all likelihood fail to be a $\mathbb{P}$-name. Such a situation shouldn't preclude $\tau$ from being a $\mathbb{P}$-name.